# To close webengage or clickdesk poup using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I got a webengage or clickdesk alert popup but that is intermittent, so I can't check everytime or wait for it to load, everytime I enter a new webpage because that would make my test case run very slow. Is there any workaround for it ( may be blocking it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For WebEngage, all you got to do is call the respective `clear()` methods for the products being used on the site (to get rid of the corresponding UI components), as underneath:

```
webengage.feedback.clear();
webengage.notification.clear();
webengage.survey.clear();
```

However, this would only work when WebEngage has loaded on the page. If you'd like to completely disable loading of WebEngage products, insert this code in head tag of the page you are testing:

```
var window._weq = {};
_weq['webengage.defaultRender'] = false;
```

You can do a lot more cool stuff like the above using our JavaScript API: http://docs.webengage.com/api/js-api-v-4.0.html

Avlesh | CEO, WebEngage

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ClickDesk on your website and would like to delete the Proactive rules which pop up the chat window randomly, then these can be deleted or edited to change the frequency from this link on your ClickDesk Dashboard - https://my.clickdesk.com/#proactive.

In case, you do not want the chat widget to show up at all until clicked on a text link or an image link then, you can add our Custom image link or text link code on your website, this would enable the chat widget only when clicked on it. You can find this link here - https://my.clickdesk.com/#departments/default.

If you have further questions or concerns with regards to ClickDesk, you can visit our website www.clickdesk.com and chat with one of our agents online.

Thanks

Mike Evans
ClickDesk Corporation